# Laravel 7 - Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am getting a error which says `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null`

I checked following possibilities but nothing worked.

I have set `name` fillable property

[image: fillable property]

Tried running seeders (even the default seeder which is already present)
[image: seeder]

And also Laravel Tinker

[image]

Comment: Can you share your migration file?

Comment: Are you also using `$guarded` in your model?

Comment: @EdwardChew sure here it is https://codeshare.io/aYEQL3

Comment: @apokryfos no im not using any guarded

Comment: please share the whole user model (without relation)

Comment: @OMR https://codeshare.io/aYEQL3 added at the top.

Comment: strange ... what in App\Traits\UserStampsTrait ?

Comment: please try $user=new User(); $user->name='test'; $user->email='test@test.com';
$user->password=bcrypt('passsword'); $user->save();

Comment: @OMR userstamp inserts created_by, updated_by and deleted_by, and I tried as you said but no success here is the image https://i.imgur.com/rZjsjTt.png

Comment: Please, share App\Traits\UserStampsTrait code.